# Select records that intersect more than 3 polygons

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql

I am analyzing parcels in land use zones.

Some parcels overlap 3 or more zones = I am interested in selecting  *only*  those records (i.e. the purple-colored parcels)

[image]

At this point I have a query that joins zones in `zoning` to parcels in `parcels` when an intersection occurs

```
SELECT t.*, m.*
FROM parcels AS t
LEFT JOIN zoning AS m
ON ST_Intersects(t.geom, m.geom)
```

However, `ST_Intersection()` only returns `true` or `false` .  Is there a way to "count" the intersections and specify 3 or more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use aggregate function **count** and **GROUP BY** with **HAVING**. I supposed there is a primary key column (id) in parcels table.

```
SELECT t.id, count(*) 
  FROM parcels AS t INNER JOIN zoning AS m ON ST_Intersects(t.geom, m.geom)
  GROUP BY t.id HAVING count(*) > 2
```